# How to write an image to file – Java ImageIO

Tags: java, image, spring-boot, javax.imageio, r.java-file

I would like to write an image to a file using Java ImageIO. This is my piece of code:

```
Document doc = convertDocument (fileName, "grey");                       
      ImageIO.write(Converter.convertSVGToPNG(doc), "png",
              new File(FOLDER_PNG_OUT_GREY + fileName.replaceAll(".svg", ".png")));
```

But I get this error when running my code:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Work\eclipse-tdk\svgManager\svgManager\src\main\resources\icons\svg\grey_png\$pac.png (The system cannot find the path specified)

I also tried:

```
String pngFileName = FOLDER_PNG_OUT_GREY + fileName.replaceAll(".svg", ".png");
File outputfile = new File(pngFileName);
bImage = ImageIO.read(outputfile);
```

but then I got the error:
**Can't read input file!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to get your image resource with the `getResource(String file)` method like this:

```
File initialImage = new File(YourClass.class.getResource("pac.png").getFile());
```